# Including all file matching regex razor cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to include Angular2 build files in a CSHTML file.

Currently, my include is:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

But Angular2 produce, on each prod build, files with different identifiers in the file name.

```
chunk    {0} main.2e0750e4cb976b8dca8a.bundle.js (main) 15.8 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.b64dd2f7c2e3011c4efb.bundle.css (styles) 154 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.e7e62c29938f18f13e86.bundle.js (scripts) 128 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.05b8df0708b580c61647.bundle.js (vendor) 3.42 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.1b4aa06545162c1bb581.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

I don't want to deactivate (if it's even possible) the fact these identifiers are included (for non-cache purpose). A person answered on a github issue page **some regex could be used** to make the include:

```
/(main|styles|scripts|vendor|inline).*.bundle.(map|js|css)/g
```

But I don't see how to pass it to my C#/cshtml file.

It should result on **including all files matching the pattern in a given directory** (wwwroot, or ~ as a shortcut).

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `asp-src-include` tag helper for scripts and `asp-href-include` for links (css).

```
<script asp-src-include="~/dist/main.*.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<link asp-href-include="~/dist/styles.*.bundle.css"/>
```

However iirc you can't use regex inside it, only globbed path (i.e. `dist/**/*.js` where ** will look through all child folders too.

If that do not suit your needs, you need to write your own tag helper.

See GitHub for current implementations of [LinkTagHelper](http://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/LinkTagHelper.cs) and [ScriptTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ScriptTagHelper.cs).

I wouldn't recommend you to use regex for the main-part anyways, because you have no control on in which order the files are included. So it's best to control this manually and only make the identifier/hashsum variable.